# How to stream video from URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, video-streaming

When I try to stream a video from a url, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

Obviously, I've tested and my source works great. Here's a simplified [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2m1rL9j/1/), and here's a copy of the code in that fiddle:

```
// Create HTML Video Element to play the video
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function (e) {
    document.body.appendChild( video );
});

video.src = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4';
video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
video.loop = true;
video.play();
```

What do I need to change in order to get it working?

Comment: run from http (not https) and remove the `video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';` part

Comment: Thanks! It's already http :-), but why wouldn't https work? Also, it is being loaded cross-origin, right? So why do I need to remove that?

Comment: you can view http resources from an https page. TBH, I don't know why removing the cross-origin stuff fixed the fiddle (i'm about to look that up), but it did...

Comment: the `crossOrigin` is only needed when using an off-site authenticated resource.

Comment: Okay sooo...what if I'm on an HTTPS domain and *need* to use an https video url? Then I'd need crossOrigin, right?

Comment: no, if you're all-https you don't need anything. crossOrigin is for preventing basic authentication credentials leaking, which is not a common situation anyway...

Comment: here's an updated fiddle for ya https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/rLxytsmm/

Comment: you should read this though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then and this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37628027/1675954

Comment: @RachelGallen, your updated example fails and shows `Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.` in the console.

Comment: @Pete it runs on my machine.. i only commented out the cross-origin line. Actually i changed it to https also