# Promise reject() in async function causes “Uncaught (in promise)” warning

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

The following code snippet causes an *"Uncaught exception warning"* when `reject(err)` is called, although the method is called inside a try/catch statement.

```
async verifyToken (token: string): Promise<string | object> {
    return new Promise<string | object>( (resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.verify(token, this._publicKey, (err, decoded) => {
             if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(decoded);
         };
     });
}
```

This violates my understanding about promisses and the async/await pattern, because up to now I do not expect an unhandling error if the function is called inside a try/catch statement.

```
try {
    const obj = await verifyToken(token);
} catch (err) {
    ...
}
```

At the moment I avoid this problem with a work arround.

```
async verifyToken (token: string): Promise<string | object> {
    let cause: any;
    const rv = await new Promise<string | object>( (resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.verify(token, this._publicKey, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                cause = err;
                resolve(undefined);
            } else {
                resolve(decoded);
            };
        })
    });
    if (rv) {
        return rv;
    } else if (cause instanceof Error) {
        throw cause;
    } else {
        throw new Error('invalid token');
    }
}
```

My questions:

- Why does the catch not solve this problem?
- Is there any better solution to avoid an *unhandled error* in promisses inside an async function?

Comment: Your `try`/`catch` code is correct, so something else is going on. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: IIRC this is just an IDE problem where the debugger pauses on handled rejections as well, you are not actually getting an `unhandledRejection` event in node right?

Comment: @Bergi, your are right, I am working with vscode and the IDE stops at this line when automatic breakpoints for Uncaught Exceptions are enabled. I am using Node.js v8.9.3 and vscode 1.18.1.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, and I'm sorry but I just stumbled upon this a moment ago searching for something else, but I think I have the answer to this specific problem.

`Promise` will neither `resolve` nor `reject` in the cast that `jwt.verify()` `throws` its own error. Guessing that the lib is `jsonwebtoken` or something like that I suspect that you have passed an invalid token and that the method does a `throw new Error('Invalid token')`

I think further to that you're mixing some ideas if you are going to return a `new Promise` you likely shouldn't use the `async` keyword.

Suggestion,

```
function verifyToken(token: string): Promise<ABetterType> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      jwt.verify(token, this._publicKey, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
          return;
        }
        resolve(decoded)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err)
    }
  });
}
```

OR (what I think I would've tried)

```
function verifyToken(token: string): Promise<ABetterType> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, this._publicKey);
      resolve(decoded);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

with async/await:

```
//some async function
try {
    let response = await getAllPosts();
} catch(e) {`enter code here`
    console.log(e);
}
```

More here: ["Uncaught (in promise) undefined" error when using with=location in Facebook Graph API query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624322/uncaught-in-promise-undefined-error-when-using-with-location-in-facebook-gra)